# Merge two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a two mysql tables that I want to merge together in one query. It's best described by an example:

```
table: users
| user_id | username |
| 1       | jason    |
| 2       | justin   |

table: user_data
| user_id | key   | data            |
| 1       | email | jason@email.com |
| 1       | phone | 555-123-4567    |
| 2       | email | justin@email.com|
| 2       | phone | 555-765-4321    |


query results:
| user_id | username | email            | phone        |
| 1       | jason    | jason@email.com  | 555-123-4567 |
| 2       | justin   | justin@email.com | 555-765-4321 |
```

You can assume that the keys are pretty uniform among all of the users (ie. all users have an email and phone). My first thought would be to do something like this but I'm curious if there is a better way:

```
SELECT *,e.data as email,p.data as phone FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN user_data AS e ON e.user_id=u.user_id AND `key`='email'
  LEFT JOIN user_data AS p ON p.user_id=u.user_id AND `key`='phone';
```

Comment: I think that is exactly what you want. Why do you think there might be a better way?

Comment: Yep, agreed.  You could be fancy and PIVOT the user_data table as a subquery, but don't think that would perform any better, and would complicate it.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way. This is a simple example with only two fields. In real life, it's only going to get longer and longer as the number of keys grow.

Comment: Given these tables, JOIN is how you would do it. However, I am not convinced it's such a good idea to have one table with all the user data as separate rows. Assuming both email and phone can appear multiple times per user, I would typically have one table with user_email and one with user_phone

Comment: Agreed with Paul, you could look at this as a sort of crosstab/pivot-table application.

Comment: PIVOT is especially good advice if the number of fields is growing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all users have an email and phone

Then why not add columns for them in the original table?

```
table: users
| user_id | username | email | phone  |
| 1       | jason    | ....  | ....   |
| 2       | justin   | ....  | ....   |
```

It will make querying much easier and faster.

The design you are using is called [Entity-attribute-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (EAV) and is generally useful when there are many attributes but they are sparsely populated.

Assuming you can't or don't want to change the table design,  the only change I'd make to your query is to not use `SELECT *`. List the columns explicitly.

Comment: Because this was just an example and the application that it applies to calls for this type of table schema.

Comment: @jasonlfunk: Then your example is a bad one. A better use-case for EAV is to store patient medical records. The example you gave is a great example of when you should try to avoid EAV.

Comment: My example was good for the information that I was trying asking for. I could have included more information as to why my schema didn't need to change, but that would just add fluff to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mark Bayers.

However, if you sticking to your design, you should consider this: is it possible that one user could have more than one email? or more than one phone? If that is the case, then you will get all combinations of phone and email per user.

If you just want one row for each user, with all the data in the respective fields, you could try this:

```
SELECT     users.id, users.username
,          GROUP_CONCAT(IF(user_data.key = 'email', user_data.data, NULL)) emails
,          GROUP_CONCAT(IF(user_data.key = 'phone', user_data.data, NULL)) phones
FROM       users
INNER JOIN user_data
ON         users.id = user_data.user_id
GROUP BY   users.id
```